# What can cause "No Data Recieved ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"?

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, server

[My website](http://vikingchan.org) does this a lot, usually when I have a thread open. I think it might be because I am constantly (every 10 seconds or so) looking for new posts and notifications and loading them in through Ajax, but this shouldn't cause this error, right?

I use GoDaddy as a host, but in my previous tries of contacting them and asking for help they've not been useful. I am not sure if it's my code or their servers that cause this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It's been a while since I've been working on the site, since I kind of abandoned it after the error constantly happened and I couldn't find any answers as to why.

Comment: Hi, i am facing the same issue. did you get a resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using shared hosting with GoDaddy?  GoDaddy shared hosting throttles the number of requests a hosted application can receive.  If you have AJAX requests sending requests every 10 seconds, it will ignore a good proportion of those requests.

I recommend setting up a test server on the [AWS cloud](http://aws.amazon.com/free/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_US&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=cloud_computing_hv_b&sc_content=aws_core_e&sc_detail=aws&sc_category=cloud_computing&sc_segment=67361869722&sc_matchtype=e&sc_country=US&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!67361869722!e!!g!!aws&ef_id=VYw6TwAABZ8qf6@k:20150802203846:s) and porting the app over there.  You'll get your own virtual server and the first year of hosting is free if you choose the smallest server size.

Comment: I'll give it a try! Do you think this could cause the No Data Received error?

Comment: @Odin Yes, the `No Data Received` response is an indication that your request was received, but probably ignored

Comment: Alright, I have another domain on another host that I'll try it out on. Thanks!

Comment: By the way I have "Deluxe Linux hosting". Is there any way I can "check" if they have throttled any of my requests? EDIT: I checked some more and the server-IP is shared so I guess I'll have to change..